# How can I extract words before some string?

Tags: python, string

I have several strings like this:

```
mylist = ['pearsapple','grapevinesapple','sinkandapple'...]
```

I want to parse the parts before apple and then append to a new list:

```
new = ['pears','grapevines','sinkand']
```

Is there a way other than finding starting points of 'apple' in each string and then appending before the starting point?

Comment: Why not `str.replace` "apple" with ""?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Is `apple` in every element in the list?

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific with exactly what form your strings take, imagine a list `['pearsapple', 'appleapple', 'appleapples', 'sinkandtoast', 'appleflavouredapple']`, it would create havoc with many approaches

Comment: @Chris_Rands is correct. In my answer I assumed that every word contains the substring "apple" (but does not have to end with "apple") and OP wants all the preceding letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By also using string split and list comprehension

```
new = [x.split('apple')[0] for x in mylist]
['pears', 'grapevines', 'sinkand']
```

Answer (score 2):

By using slicing in combination with the `index` method of strings.

```
>>> [x[:x.index('apple')] for x in mylist]
['pears', 'grapevines', 'sinkand']
```

You could also use a regular expression

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.match('(.*?)apple', x).group(1) for x in mylist]
['pears', 'grapevines', 'sinkand']
```

I don't see why though.

Comment: The second one only works if `apple` is in every word.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the word `apple` will be fix (fixed length word), then we can use:

```
second_list = [item[:-5] for item in mylist]
```

Comment: That's a good solution if all the strings are guaranteed to end with "apple" and contain only one "apple".

Comment: Yeah. Right. It works for fixed length word substring. :)

Comment: Yeah. Right  @Drako

Answer (score 2):

If some elements in the list don't contain `'apple'` at the end of the string, this regex leaves the string untouched:

```
>>> import re
>>> mylist = ['pearsapple','grapevinesapple','sinkandapple', 'test', 'grappled']
>>> [re.sub('apple$', '', word) for word in mylist]
['pears', 'grapevines', 'sinkand', 'test', 'grappled']
```

Comment: @timgeb: True. We do need more info from OP. It could be `None`, the original string or an empty string. I'd argue the original string is still a better choice than your `AttributeError: 'NoneType'` ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to iterate through every string in the list and then use the `split()` string function.

```
for word in mylist:
    word = word.split("apple")[0]
```